# delay in text input

Tags: java, swt

User is typing something in Text component. When he is stopped typing for 1 second I want get text and handle it.
I try to do like that

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            timer.purge();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //handler
                    System.out
                            .println("MainClass.main(...).new SelectionAdapter() {...}.widgetSelected(...).new TimerTask() {...}.run()");
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

But this code works incorrectly

Comment: code part in run() triggered everytime when the user types symbol

Comment: I don't see you halting for 1 second anywhere in that code....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked by myself and I'll answer by myself :) *timer* is private member

```
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            if(timer != null){
                timer.cancel();
            }
            timer = new Timer();                
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //handler
                    System.out
                        .println("MainClass.main(...).new SelectionAdapter() {...}.widgetSelected(...).new TimerTask() {...}.run()");
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

works!

Comment: Thanks, I did this a while back but forgot the code, this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

> ```
> double last_edit = 0;
> // this method shall be called on initialization of your Text component
> void run() {
>     new Thread(new Runnable() {
>         public void run() {
>             if (last_edit < 0) {
>                 // hande your text here
>                 last_edit = 1;
>             } else {
>                 last_edit -= 0.1d;
>             }
>             try {
>                 Thread.sleep(100);
>             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
>             }
>         }
>     }).start();
> }
> ```

```
 Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
 text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
    @Override
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
        last_edit = 1;
    }
 });
```